# Thymeleaf - How to pass HTML to the div?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

How to pass HTML from a variable to a `div`?

I have code

```
<div class="content" th:text="${ourService.getShortText()}" />
```

But it shows not HTML in the `div`, but escaped HTML as `div` text.
How to pass the variable's value not as an escaped text, but as inner HTML of the `div`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
<div class="content" th:utext="${ourService.getShortText()}" />
```